# Angular routing is not working with particular module and particular route only, no matter what component I put there

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have various modules in my Angular application. Routing for children components is working perfectly fine in other modules but in the module I am about to share, routing is not working except for the first '' blank route in children. I have been trying hard since long. Please look into the code, any insights would be helpful.

**Editor Module**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [EditorNavComponent, EditorDashboardComponent, SubmittedArticleComponent, SubmittedArticlesComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    JournalModule,
    MaterialModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: 'editor',
        component: EditorNavComponent,
        // canActivate: [AuthGuard, EditorGuard],
        // canLoad: [EditorGuard],
        // canActivateChild: [EditorGuard],
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            component: EditorDashboardComponent,
            pathMatch: 'full'
          },
          {
            path: 'journals/:journal_Id',
            component: JournalEditorComponent,
            children: [
              {
                path: 'articles',
                component: SubmittedArticlesComponent
              },
              {
                path: 'articles/:articleId',
                component: SubmittedArticleComponent
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]),
    AuthorModule
  ],
  providers: [EditorGuard],
  exports: []
})
```

**editor-nav.component.html**

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="example-container mt-5">

  <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side"
               [opened]="this.loginService.tokenSubject.value && this.sideNavService.toggleNav.value"
               style="background-color: rgb(1, 134, 151);">
    <div class="thin-scrollbar scrollbar-deep-purple bordered-deep-purple thin">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="mt-3 text-center font-weight-bold" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Home</h5>
<!-- Links here-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </mat-sidenav>

  <mat-sidenav-content class="mt-2">
    <!-- <p><button mat-mini-fab color="warn" class="btn-xs mt-2" (click)="sidenav.toggle()"><mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_right</mat-icon></button></p> -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

I use the  in the parent route's component's template which renders the child component.

**Now**, the thing here to notice is very strange. If I put the `JournalEditorComponent` in place of `EditorDashboardComponent`, it loads like a charm. Also, when I logout of the application and comment the guards I have setup above, angular let me navigate to wherever I want. This seemed like a problem in guards, but I also commented the guards and logged in to the application, yet it doesn't load `JournalEditorComponent`. It doesn't give me any error. Just behaves as there is no such route and goes back to home which in this case: `/editor`.

I have also tried removing the route params and changing the '' route to anything else like 'abc' etc but nothing else worked.

Please let me know if you need to know anything else.

Thank you so much!

***UPDATE***

I was actually entering the route directly in the address bar. It works fine when I go through router link or button. This might be resolved by using **nginx**. But the problem is already answered on stack overflow.

Comment: Hi. Can you try to change canLoad guard to canActivate?

Comment: I have even tried to comment these out without success.

Comment: Could you create a stackblitz demo?

Comment: My angular project is actually linked with a dotnet core backend. But sure let me reproduce the problem on stackblitz

Comment: I still won't be able to link my backend with stackblitz and it is required as I mentioned the route works after logout